# How to show multiple query results in one view?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to show results from multiple select queries in one view. I've tried to google it without success. Any suggestions?

Example:

Query 1

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' ) AS Col1
  FROM table1 
 WHERE column1 like '%Group1%'
```

The query gives something like this:

**Col1** 
 1000
  1000
  1000
  135

Query 2

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' ) AS Col2
  FROM table1
 WHERE column1 like '%Group2%'
```

Results in:

**Col2** 
 1000
  1000
  1000
   1000
  1000
 46

I want to show the count results of both queries in one view with separate columns. Also the results are shown in multiple rows instead of one. How can I sum up the numbers of all rows? All suggestions appreciated! The final result should be something like this

**Col1 | Col2**
3135 | 5046

Comment: You can't have the results of two different queries in asingle tab on the Query results tab. What you can do is, pin the query results for individual queries and then do your analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps UNION or UNION ALL would help?

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' )
  FROM table1
 WHERE column1 like '%Group1%'
UNION ALL
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' )
  FROM table1
 WHERE column1 like '%Group2%';
```

If you really need columns, perhaps something like:

```
SELECT
  A.cnt1,
  b.cnt2
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' ) cnt1,
      ROWNUM AS rwn
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      column1 LIKE '%Group1%'
  )
  a
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' ) cnt2,
      ROWNUM AS rwn
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      column1 LIKE '%Group2%'
  )
  b
ON
  a.rwn = b.rwn;
```

And for the SUMS that you added, you can again use simple subselects in SELECT.

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' )) AS Col1
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      column1 LIKE '%Group1%'
  ) AS res1,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(REGEXP_COUNT( column1, '</Expression>' )) AS Col1
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      column1 LIKE '%Group2%'
  ) AS res2
FROM
dual;
```

Comment: A third option would be conditional aggregates e.g.  `REGEXP_COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%Group1%' THEN Column1 END, '</Expression>' )`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers. I have problem getting them in seperate columns in one view like you suggested. I think it's because of the differences in the number of resulted rows from the queries. I just updated my question, it gives a better explanation of what i'm trying to do.  Please give guidance since i'm new to sql! :)

Comment: @user3037266: I fixed the second query, it was expecting only single row from the subselects. Note that your desired output is rather uncommon and has to be produced usign the ROWNUM pseudocolumn to JOIN two outputs to each other.